# Pyrogram как ловить 2 хандлера сразу

Tags: python, pyrogram

В функции пытаюсь словить 2 хандлера, но ловится только первое событие. если поменять местами, то  будет ловиться только событие о новом сообщении.

```
@app.on_raw_update()
def handle_chat_permissions(Client, update, ex1, ex2):
    print('upd')

@app.on_message()
def msg_handler(Client, message):
    print('MSG')
```